# What does "before" mean in the context of a theatre?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does **before** mean in this sentence?

> Theatre or theater is a collaborative form of fine art that uses live performers, typically actors, to present the experience of a real or imagined event **before** a live audience in a specific place, often a stage.

[Source of the article [Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatre)

Comment: Generally means "in front of"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The girl stood before her, painting.
>
> I was standing before her door with flowers in my hands.

*Before*, in the present case, means *in front of*.

Comment: Or even "the girl stood before her painting".

Comment: ..but not "the girl stood, before her painting"

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you could probably find a simpler sentence as an example. And a link to a definition might be nice.